# Set css to $templateCache.get() html in link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This directive is executed for everyday in a schedule table. After I have rendered the event I wanna be able to modify the css properties depending on some stuff.

The problem is that when the event from $templateCache.get("event.html") is rendered, I can't access its elements because the id is still id="drag_{{u.id}}_{{e.id}}" and not id="drag_1_1".

I tried scope.$apply() but dosen't seem to be the answer. 
Does it have something to do with that Im not compiling the template?

```
app.directive("renderEvent", function($templateCache) {

   return {
       template: $templateCache.get("event.html"),
       restrict: 'EA',
       scope : {
               u : '=', //User
               e : '=' //Event
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              //TRYING DO THIS $(#drag_1_1).css({"margin-top": "35px"});
              //console.log($(#drag_1_1)) is showing context undefined
       }
   };
});
```

event.html:

```
<div ng-controller="scheduleController" id="drag_{{u.id}}_{{e.id}}" class="event">
<div class="event2" id="myHandle_{{u.id}}_{{e.id}}">
    <div class="eventDetailsWrapper"
         title="{{e.title + '\n'}}From {{e.start | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} to {{e.end | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}{{'\n'}}Total work days: {{e.end - e.start}}{{'\n'}}Allocation: {{e.occupied * 100}}%{{'\n'}}Client: ICA">
        <b>{{e.title}}</b> - Google 100% for 3 work days
    </div>
</div>
```

Part of the table code:

```
<td class="dropArea" id="drop_{{d| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}_{{u.id}}"
       ng-repeat="d in dates" ng-click="setTempData(u, d);">

  <!-- LOOP EVENTS IN USER -->
  <div ng-repeat="e in u.events" ng-if="d === e.start">
    <render-event u="u" e="e">   </render-event>
  </div>

</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed the template is retrieved asynchronous. For sure you can inline your template code. But it's more likely to change your css depending on your model porperties. To achieve this you may use [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) or [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle). Suppose your events have a property `type` and the values are '`private`' and '`business`' you may write in your template:

```
<div class="eventDetailsWrapper" title="..." 
     ng-class="{'private': e.type==='private', 'business': e.type==='business'}">
    <b>{{e.title}}</b>
</div>
```

For expample this will add the class `private` to your element if the event `type` is private.

It is also possible change the css directly (but i would avoid this):

```
<div class="eventDetailsWrapper" title="..." 
     ng-style="{'background-color': e.type==='private'? 'blue', 'red'}">
    <b>{{e.title}}</b>
</div>
```